# How to find out if a logo has already been used/exists?

Tags: website-features

I have few concepts of logos for a website. How do I know a specific concept that is finalized, is already used by some other website or not?

Comment: Not a full answer, but http://tineye.com/ might find logos similar to yours.

Comment: If the logo is trademarked, you can do a trademark search (for US trademarks): http://www.uspto.gov/products/library/ptdl/services/tmsearch.jsp : *If your mark incorporates a design or logo you must search for trademarks that might be confusingly similar. Use the index in the back of the Design Code Manual to locate the appropriate six-digit code for each design element in your mark. For example, a logo depicting an eagle would be coded 03.15.01. Each element in a logo is assigned a design code. Carefully review the guidelines for each category.*

Comment: @artlung, I think that's the closet approach that you have suggested. As a test, I tried to upload Google logo & the site did show me several Google logos indicating that the logo exists. Now I took the logo of this website (webmasters.stackexchange.com) & tested it. There were no results to be found. So this means that the website was unable to find the match, although it existed. So under this situation, I think the chances of finding out if the logo exists is just 50-50 or maybe even less. What do you say?

Comment: @Devner, I agree, there's not a perfect mechanism to find out if a logo exists. I'm comfortable adding comments here, but not adding an answer per se. I'm hoping you find a way that is useful.

Comment: @JasonBirch, that is one good resource that you have mentioned. I am still in the process of testing the website. Have you ever used it yourself? If yes, any helpful results that you might want to share? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid trademark violations, there is no way around involving a lawyer. They can assist you in doing a search. Even then, there could be challenges. In the US, at least, a logo does not have to be registered to enjoy trademark protection. Prior evidence of trade using that mark (or one sufficiently similar under a "reasonable person" test) in a similar area of trade constitutes precedence. Defending and losing a trademark battle can be expensive due to costs of implementing changes and the possibility of penalties, not to mention legal fees. I am not a lawyer, so this is just a rough approximation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand that. But even a lawyer can do only so much. There may be more than a billion websites out there & more than a million unique logos (at least I hope). So what are the chances that a lawyer can really search a million logos(at the very least) & come up with accurate findings? Even a lawyer will have no option other than to search. So why don't we do the 'search' ourselves? Just a thought.

Comment: @Devner: It's called "due dilligence" and it spreads the blame, er, risk.

Answer (score 1):

I use reverse image search on Google. It has always worked for me.

But the significant disadvantage is that you should get a coarse "keymage" (key-image) ready for searching.

All the best searching.

Comment: Reverse image? Are you referring to the image search feature on Google?

Comment: Yes. You are right.